# Brake Rotors pitted after only ~5000Km

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, brake-calipers, braking, brake-pad

I changed the brake pads and discs/rotors a while ago, at 200K km, on my 2006 Skoda Octavia. Previous ones were pitted as well so I was just happy to be able to brake properly. But at around 205K km the braking hops were back.

What hurts more is that I went with Brembo and spent quite a sum of money on them.

My car is currently at around 213K km and can't really afford to replace rotors and pads again because I will have to do timing belt, tensioner, water pump and the whole gang.

I also think I should mention that my rear-right caliper is not OEM, at some point it got stuck and service guys were like 'we need to replace this asap' and now I believe I have something of questionable quality installed.

Also I rev-match a lot because I find it fun. Could this somehow impact my brakes and cause excessive wear? I wouldn't really think so because from my understanding the engine braking force just helps you stop.

Any advice on what I should consider doing or stop doing next would be much much appreciated :)

EDIT:
the pitting is not visible, the surface of the discs is smooth, however they become slightly oval which shouldn't have happened over the course of 5000km

Comment: Why would you have to change the timing belt etc if you service your brakes?

Comment: How much time has passed since you serviced the brakes last?

Comment: Is the car sat for long periods between use?

Comment: Would it be possible to get some photographs of the pitting?  Are all wheels equally affected or just one axle / wheel?

Comment: the timing belt is just a plan for now, i still have quite some km to go untill the next change and i will change it at the same time with the filters and oil

Comment: i serviced my brakes when the car had 200k km, now i'm at around 213k km, been driving with the discs as they are because money

Comment: no, the car doesn't really sit, maybe a week from time to time and 2 weeks very rarely

Comment: getting a photo wouldn't give off any conclusive fact, since it wouldn't be distinguishable, what is though is the "bumps" while braking. not all wheels are affected apparently, just tested this, rear ones move freely, front ones have some kind of bump in their spinning

Comment: You need to describe the braking problems you are having in more detail. If your rotors have no visual pitting then they are not pitted, something else is going wrong.

Comment: HandyHowie was asking **how much time**, not distance, it had been since the brake job.

Comment: not much time, i'd say about two months tops

Comment: it's not really pitting i think, i couldn't really find the term for it, but the idea is that now they're slightly oval compared to when i installed them